# load html page on click on packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying out packaged apps, and I would like to know how to load a new html page when clicked.
So I have to pages: index.html and settings.html. When settings is clicked, settings.html is loaded.
How do I navigate form page to page or do I just create a new window?

nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps don't navigate. Like with a native app, you'd probably want to open your settings page in a separate window. Here is a near-duplicate question with an answer presenting multiple options: [Chrome packaged apps local root html links via Sandbox Manifest 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049763/chrome-packaged-apps-local-root-html-links-via-sandbox-manifest-2/16073572#16073572).

Comment: Hi, that is what I did after all!