# "Can't open same-window link" when dropping a file on a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

This error message pop up in the terminal while I try to handle file dropping in chrome packaged app:

> Can't open same-window link to "path/to/some/file.txt"; try target="_blank".

This is the code I was using:

```
$.fn.extend({
    filedrop: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            callback : null
        }
        options =  $.extend(defaults, options)
        return this.each(function() {
            var files = []
            var $this = $(this)

            // Stop default browser actions
            $this.bind('dragover dragleave', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation()
                event.preventDefault()
            })

            // Catch drop event
            $this.bind('drop', function(event) {
                // Stop default browser actions
                event.stopPropagation()
                event.preventDefault()

                // Get all files that are dropped
                files = event.originalEvent.target.files || event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files

                // Convert uploaded file to data URL and pass trought callback
                if(options.callback) {
                    var reader = new FileReader()
                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        options.callback(event.target.result)
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
                }
                return false
            })
        })
    }
})
// Event listener filedropper
$('.dropbox').filedrop({
    callback : function(fileEncryptedData) {
        console.log(fileEncryptedData);
    }
})
```

Is this something to do with chrome app permission or something in my code. There's already `e.stopPropagation` in there so i have no idea why.

Comment: Try this if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049763/chrome-packaged-apps-local-root-html-links-via-sandbox-manifest-2

Comment: i simply want to cancel the navigation as act as if the file dropped was to be uploaded

Comment: what about using event.preventDefault() ???

Comment: i already have that in my code but it doesnt fix it i don't think

Comment: could i use `webview` for this? if so how?

Comment: Google search also turned up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381943/cant-open-same-window-link-when-dropping-a-file-on-a-chrome-app which points to Chrome App samples that claim to implement this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-codelab/tree/master/lab5_data/javascript/2_drop_files